# How to setup hardware accelerated VNC on Ubuntu machine without a dedicated monitor

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, vnc-server

I have a desktop PC with NVidia graphics card which is running Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop. The default VNC server stops accepting connections when I disconnect physical monitor. I solved this problem by using TightVNC server. But it doesn't use hardware acceleration (e.g. it's virtual monitor doesn't support OpenGL). Is it possible at all to have VNC session that uses NVidia driver on a PC without a monitor?

Comment: I switched to vulkan for this purpose. Using vulkan on server is much more comfortable then opengl.

Comment: Do you want to run your own opengl code on server, or you need to run some routines that you can not edit?

Comment: @Hihikomori I want to run apps from different vendors

Comment: Check if [this](https://medium.com/@BuyMiners/3-best-ways-to-use-an-hdmi-dummy-plug-or-display-emulator-e74cb8712790) can help.

Comment: @Hihikomori Thank you. This is definitely an option but if possible I would try to go with software solution if not than this is very good fallback option.

Comment: When opengl context initializes, it always try's to find display, and fails if there is no display. There is a softwhere display emulator "xvfb", but it supports only opengl 3.0.

Comment: @Hihikomori If I create a manual xorg.conf file without having a display connected will it work?

Comment: If some soft desired to render somthing on a display with gpu, there must be a display connected.